# Why does Firebase deeplink not open my app?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

I setup everything regarding this guide: https://github.com/bizz84/firebase_auth_demo_flutter/blob/master/docs/sign-in-email-link.md

I've added a firebase domain:

[image]

and a dynmic url:

[image]

Now I call this function in my app:

```
_firebaseAuth.sendSignInWithEmailLink(
      email: email,
      url: 'https://framr-test.firebaseapp.com/',
      handleCodeInApp: true,
      iOSBundleID: packageInfo.packageName,
      androidPackageName: packageInfo.packageName,
      androidInstallIfNotAvailable: true,
      androidMinimumVersion: '21',
    );
```

The package name is the same as the one in AndroidManifest.xml. Now I receive an email with a link the following params per E-Mail:

```
https://sykori.page.link/?
link=https://framr-test.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action? 
apiKey=...&
mode=signIn&
oobCode=...&
continueUrl=https://framr-test.firebaseapp.com/
&lang=en
&apn=com.sykori.framr
&amv=21
&ibi=com.sykori.framr
&ifl=...
```

When clicking on the link on my phone I will be redirected to https://framr-test.firebaseapp.com/ and then to the play store but the app does not open. The app is installed only via Android Studio. For SHA1 and SHA256 I used the keys from the debug keystore.

Comment: Try visiting https://sykori.page.link/Tbeh?d=1 and addressing the error.